# How to build dagger itself

Tags: dagger, bazel

The [dagger](https://github.com/google/dagger) project uses [bazel.build](http://bazel.build) system to build. I have installed bazel on Fedora, it runs and builds the project but apparently dagger has Java 1.8 code, and bazel targets java 7.

There is a [build_def.bzl](https://github.com/google/dagger/blob/master/build_defs.bzl) file and java target version is defined like so: 
`SOURCE_7_TARGET_7 = ["-source 1.7 -target 1.7"]`

changing it to 
`SOURCE_7_TARGET_7 = ["-source 1.8 -target 1.8"]`

does not help. Both master and rc11 branches fail to build because of the same error (java compiler complains about target version 1.7 not supporting lambda and method reference). There is no guide for building dagger on the wiki or project page and I'm unfamiliar with bazel. I wonder if something like [retrolambda](https://github.com/orfjackal/retrolambda) must be added to the build runtime path but it doesn't seem easy with bazel.

Sample output:

```
$> bazel build :all

INFO: Found 8 targets...
ERROR: /home/user/dagger/java/dagger/internal/codegen/BUILD:44:1: Building java/dagger/internal/codegen/libcodegen.jar (116 source files) failed: java failed: error executing command external/local_jdk/bin/java -Xbootclasspath/p:external/bazel_tools/third_party/java/jdk/langtools/javac-9-dev-r4023-2.jar -XX:+TieredCompilation '-XX:TieredStopAtLevel=1' -jar ... (remaining 2 argument(s) skipped): com.google.devtools.build.lib.shell.BadExitStatusException: Process exited with status 1.
java/dagger/internal/codegen/AbstractComponentWriter.java:612: error: method references are not supported in -source 1.7
  (use -source 8 or higher to enable method references)
java/dagger/internal/codegen/AnnotationExpression.java:80: error: lambda expressions are not supported in -source 1.7
  (use -source 8 or higher to enable lambda expressions)
java/dagger/internal/codegen/AnnotationSpecs.java:41: error: method references are not supported in -source 1.7
  (use -source 8 or higher to enable method references)

# Rest of output removed for brevity, the error above repeats for many more files.
```

Answer (score 0):

I had wrong version of bazel installed. Building is as simple as running:

```
bazel build :all
```

I already had Oracle JDK 8 installed on my machine (Fedora) and downloaded [this release of bazel](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/releases/download/0.5.0/bazel-0.5.0-without-jdk-installer-linux-x86_64.sh) (bazel-0.5.0-without-jdk-installer-linux-x86_64.sh).

Comment: I get this error, did you set any env? every rule of type javadoc_library implicitly depends upon the target '@local_jdk//:jdk-default', but this target could not be found because of: no such target '@local_jdk//:jdk-default': target 'jdk-default' not declared in package '' (did you mean 'jre-default'?)